# How get URLs for 1 million queries?

Tags: python-3.x, url

I have 1 million keywords, and I wanna write program that define category for every keyword via neural network. To learn my program, I need get texts (50-100) for every keyword. To get texts I need get URLs for keywords via search engine -- google, yahoo, bing, etc.

How I can do it for real time (10-30 days)? All search engines, that I know, give ban (captcha) for frequent queries from specify Python program.